# Flipping the Y axis in vtk

Tags: c++, visualization, 3d, vtk

Is there a way that I can make VTK have the Y axis go down (when increasing values) rather than up?

I'd like my VTK windows to match my non-VTK windows in displaying data, which all have the Y axis going down.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you can get away with manipulating your camera.

Try something like this:

```
// To look "into" the X axis, with Y-axis pointing downwards
vtkCamera * cam = myRenderer->GetActiveCamera();

cam->SetPosition(1, 0, 0);
cam->SetFocalPoint(0, 0, 0);
cam->SetViewUp(0, -1, 0);

// To view the full bounds of your scene
myRenderer->ResetCamera();
```

Manipulating these ivars, you should be able to work things out quite easily. If you want to do something more complex, you can set a vtkTransform to the camera using camara->SetUserTransform() and manipulate the transform instead of trying to work out camera positions.

Note however, that VTK always assumes a right-handed coordinate system. In my above example looking into X and down on Y, the Z axis increases towards the left of the screen. This may cause some confusion if you're working with a left-handed system.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your example, you seem to be moving the camera and flipping it upside down. Although this flips the Y axis, it also flips the X axis too, which is not what I want.

My data has the Y going "down" as it increases, while VTK has Y going "up". This might be something fundamental in VTK and not user-changeable.

Comment: If you are looking at the XY plane from +z with your camera up = +y, the y axis is up, and the x axis is right. If you move the camera to -z and roll the camera so camera up = y, the y axis will be down and the x axis will be right.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the newer chart code in VTK, such as vtkChartXY. I added a test showing a simple line plot on a 3D scene, [TestChartsOn3D.cxx](http://vtk.org/gitweb?p=VTK.git;a=blob;f=Charts/Testing/Cxx/TestChartsOn3D.cxx), and the vtkAxis class is designed to allow you to set a minimum and maximum going in either direction. This would be entirely independent of the 3D scene, but you could do whatever you wanted there to make it match the 2D chart or not. You would need to use VTK 5.8.0 or later though.

Comment: IMHO, this should be voted more highly - it works and is easy - you can have reversed X or Y axes as needed.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I am using QVtkWidget to display DICOM Axial volume with   direrions [-1,-1, 1]. This is what works for me:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2> imageViewer= 
                            vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2>::New();
vtkCamera * cam = imageViewer->GetRenderer()->GetActiveCamera();
cam->SetFocalPoint (0, 0, 0);
cam->SetPosition   (0, 0, -1); // Camera in Z so it display XY planes. 
cam->SetViewUp     (-1, 0, 0); // Up direction is the X not the y.  
imageViewer->GetRenderer()->ResetCamera( );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with VTK, but the function `SetReverseYAxis()` might be what you need.

Comment: Not quite, as that only applies to vtkXYPlotActor. I'd like my whole scene Y-flipped, which contains other actors.